# Python, Starlette & Docker error walking file system: OSError [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links:

Tags: python, linux, docker, mounted-volumes

I'm getting this error, even though I'm not running an os.walk or any other kind of file read/write operation with python.

When I'm running

```
find -L ./ -mindepth 15
```

I find the files involved in the loop.
Locally is the `/usr/bin/X11` and at server I'm getting the following:

`error walking file system: OSError [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr'`

and then from WatchGodReload:

`WARNING:  WatchGodReload detected file change in '['/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/1', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/3', '/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/2', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/5', '/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stderr', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/4', '/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/fd/6/dev/stdout', '/dev/fd/1']'. Reloading...`

Either I run the container with the volume I usually bind:

```
UPLOADS_PATH=/var/opt/tmp
LOCAL_UPLOADS_PATH=/var/containers/TEST_UPLOADS

docker build --build-arg POSTGRES_USER --build-arg POSTGRES_PASSWORD --build-arg POSTGRES_SERVER --build-arg POSTGRES_DB --build-arg POSTGRES_PORT --build-arg UPLOADS_PATH --build-arg WHERE_AM_I --build-arg SESSION_SECRET --build-arg DO_YOU_WANT_USERS -t test .

docker run -d --name test_container -v ${LOCAL_UPLOADS_PATH}:${UPLOADS_PATH} -p 7000:7000 test
```

or without the binding, I still get the same error logs & the app is constantly restarting after every request.

P.S. I've also tried the `docker system prune -a`, and although there were deprecated stuff, nothing changed.

Much appreciate any suggestions on what to further explore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/dev/fd` is special pseudo-device filesystem that is showing the `VFS` handles or simply said the open files of the PID that is examining the device. Trough a coincidence of the build and the running processes in the container, your image has a link to the /dev/fd the same /dev/fd that it's trying to read.

However, this it's not unusual to end in loops if you follow symbolink links on the pseudo-devices, so when using `find -L` as a super user you should exclude the `/dev`, `/sys` and `/proc` when searching and following links with `-xdev`

use

```
find -L ./ -xdev -mindepth 15
```

Comment: Followed your advice and this is the result: ➜ ~ cd /var/lib/docker/overlay2 ➜ find -L ./ -xdev -mindepth 15 ➜ find: File system loop detected; ‘./d2dba43e7cdbdec81bac529bb85908a7f859f227cda0149389f164272cb372e8/diff/usr/bin/X11’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘./d2dba43e7cdbdec81bac529bb85908a7f859f227cda0149389f164272cb372e8/diff/usr/bin’. find: File system loop detected; ‘./l/GCDLBXTJXAL5PFTI4BE3MM3OE2/usr/bin/X11’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘./l/GCDLBXTJXAL5PFTI4BE3MM3OE2/usr/bin’.

Comment: So it seems that for some reason my container has some issue with the /usr/bin/X11, although I'm not invoking or searching through the FS and my app has no screen calls, it's just a uvicorn server on a starlette app.

Comment: @Lopofsky, this is unexpected, the overlay images shouldn't have loops. Can you extract the troubleshooting information and open new question?

Comment: Thank you for your patience, it's the log at the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Following @jordanvrtanoski suggestion I'm closing this, considering it as a separate issue.

Also his/her replies allowed me to understand the nature of the issue better, hence a progress.

The followup question is here: [Docker overlay2: error walking file system: OSError [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410156/1390853)